# Class containing the instance of same class type

Tags: c++, oop

I have the requirement to contain a pointer of same class within a class ( something like link list , containing the pointer to next link ). What my requirement is something like this :

```
    class A
    {
        class A* child;
    }
```

I want to ensure that A->child->child will always be NULL and no one can change this. ( Ensuring a link list to have no more than two nodes ).

Any help ?

Comment: Do you mean that code which has an `A` object should be able to get the child object - but not the grandchild?

Comment: What I mean is that the code should be able to change the child ( which will be NULL when A gets instantiated , but then not the child of its child ( which will also be null when we create the first child ).

Comment: This is a case of "how do I do some bizarre thing to solve my problem" - we're discussing the bizarre thing instead of your actual problem. To me, since you want each level of the hierarchy to behave fundamentally differently you should use different class types for the different tree levels.

Comment: @tenfour: My thinking as well; this sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Sorry guys for the trouble . I guess I landed to a wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done, not using a single link anyways. If you have a link pointing back to the "parent" it might be done by having the `child` and `parent` member variables private, and then have special access functions that makes sure you can not add more than two links to the first object in the chain.

The reason I suggest using a "parent" chain is because you could force the first object in the chain to check it's `child` chain, but if you have access to e.g. the last object in the chain you could add *two more* children in that chain.

Comment: So basically , if i will have a parent link , i can check .. if the parent is NULL it can have a child and if parent is not NULL , it can not have a child. I guess this will do.

Answer (score 3):

Any restriction like that would be awkward (if possible). I'd go with a fixed-length array instead:

```
A* l[3];
```

if you need to prevent slicing, or simply

```
A l[3];
```

otherwise.

You could programatically enforce that restriction through something like:

```
class A
{
   A* child;
public:
   void addChild(A* newChild)
   {
       if ( child == NULL )
           child = newChild;
       else if ( child->child == NULL )
           child->child = newChild;
       else 
           throw std::exception("list is already at full capacity");
   }
}
```

Comment: When I will call addChild , I will have to create the newChild which I will pass as a parameter , what I want to ensure now is this newChild->child will always be NULL and now no one can can call addChild on this object ( or the calling will return error ). So from your solution , it doesn't ensure if I will call this on the child object instead of parent one.